# C# LINQ "inner join" of collections

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections, lambda

Basically I have a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` object and I want to get from it `IEnumerable<T>` of objects that exist in **all** of the collections.

I'm trying to code that as elegant as possible, and I'm wondering if there is some LINQ trick of doing that, preferably one-liner. If it can help, both `IEnumerable`s are `ISet`.

Currently I'm using a code similar to below:

```
// Some starting data - collection of collections
HashSet<HashSet<ulong>> data = new HashSet<HashSet<ulong>> { new HashSet<ulong> { 1, 2, 3 }, new HashSet<ulong> { 2, 3, 4 }, new HashSet<ulong> { 3, 4, 5 } };

// Flatten collection of collections into a single collection with unique elements
HashSet<ulong> result = new HashSet<ulong>(data.SelectMany(set => set));

// Remove from it all elements that are missing from 1 or more initial collections
result.RemoveWhere(number => data.Any(set => !set.Contains(number)));

// The result is: HashSet<ulong> { 3 }
```

It works, but I'm doing several things here such as enumerating initial collection twice, creating a half-ready result and iterating + removing elements from it.

I'm pretty sure there should be an option to do that in one-go with LINQ, I'm basically looking for something like:

```
HashSet<HashSet<ulong>> data = new HashSet<HashSet<ulong>> { new HashSet<ulong> { 1, 2, 3 }, new HashSet<ulong> { 2, 3, 4 }, new HashSet<ulong> { 3, 4, 5 } };elements
HashSet<ulong> result = data.LinqInnerJoinMagic(set => set);
```

Does something like this exist in C#? Maybe as an extension method? I tried hard to make use of LINQ `Join()` but I couldn't find out how to adapt it to my example, I'd appreciate a helpful hand, it's very likely that the answer is so simple that I can't really find it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes I realized I was wrong, I've already deleted that comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`HashSet<T>.IntersectWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb293080(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
HashSet<ulong> result = data.First();
foreach (HashSet<ulong> set in data.Skip(1))
    result.IntersectWith(set);
```

> Modifies the current `HashSet<T>` object to contain only elements that
>   are present in that object and in the specified collection.

Comment: Funny enough, I knew about ```IntersectWith()``` but for some reason I didn't think of such obvious solution... I'm picking it as best answer, as it enumerates over ```data``` far less than other (still valid) LINQ suggestions, so thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate combined with intersect will get you the common elements that exist in all sets.

```
var orderedData = data.ToList();
var commonSet = orderedData.Skip(1).Aggregate((IEnumerable<ulong>)(orderedData.First()), (c, n) => c.Intersect(n));
```

Comment: This one also works properly and nicely solves my issue, so I upvoted it as well. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var result = new HashSet<ulong>(
      data.SelectMany(x => x).Where(x => data.All(z => z.Contains(x)))
);
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'm now actually curious which one has the best performance... :)

Comment: This would be my top 2 pick if I didn't have magic of ```IntersectWith()``` that ```HashSet``` gives me, I recommend to use this if your initial data is not ```IEnumerable<HashSet<T>>```, I think it will work for all cases, and if somebody doesn't want to use HashSet then he can add ```Distinct()```, thanks for a nice Linq solution!